# Clover 3.1.7 does not support java 7 diamond

Tags: java, code-coverage, gradle, clover

My Clover instrumentation fails with the error:

```
>  /path/to/MyClass.java:138:28:unexpected token: >
```

On the line:

```
return new HashSet<>();
```

This is despite executing clover instrumentation with the source level explicitly set to 1.7:

```
ant."clover-instr"(srcdir:it, destdir:cloverConvention.instrSrcDir, source:"1.7")
```

( ^ gradle )

Actually, I can set that property to whatever I like. It makes no difference:

```
ant."clover-instr"(srcdir:it, destdir:cloverConvention.instrSrcDir, source:"one billion")
```

But it is a valid attribute, because if I put something else in it will fail differently.

```
ant."clover-instr"(srcdir:it, destdir:cloverConvention.instrSrcDir, sores:"1.7")
> clover-instr doesn't support the "sores" attribute
```

Do I need to do anything else to get the 1.7 source recognised? Using Clover 3.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression bug. Clover v3.1.5 works OK.